# Amazon S3 Bucket Private data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

Hello and apologies if this was asked before but I searched and could not find any similar question.

I have an Android and iOS app that allows users to transmit data between each other including images and videos and some of these data are stored on the S3 Bucket.

Currently, the S3 bucket has AES encryption SSE 256. and no encryption from client-side

I want to store the data in the S3 Bucket but I do not want even the admin to access these files but I want this to be transparent to the app which is currently released in the market.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to apply a bucket policy that explicitly denies all access to the bucket except the root (or other designated account that you control) and the application.

Comment: What do you mean by "be transparent to the app"? Are you saying that you have everything working fine using S3, but you want to make a change to block access for the Admins? Or is the app not currently using S3?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that what I will do on the Amazon S3 bucket. I do not want it to affect the app. I do not wish to change anything in the code there. As for the S3 bucket, I do not wish anyone to be able to view these photos or access these files at all. I should be able to backup the Bucket as whole if needed. but I do not want even admins to be able to access these files for privacy purposes.